# Проксирование uri на php скрипт

Tags: nginx

Необходимо перенаправлять запросы на скрипт.

Например чтоб по ссылке site.ru/dom/moy отдавалась страница site.ru/router.php?dom=moy, при этом без редиректа на скрипт(адрес в браузере должен остаться неизменным). Самой папки dom не существует на сервере

Не могу разобраться в синтаксисе nginx. Понимаю, что нужно что то вроде proxy_pass, но дальше что - хз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример настройки location. В Вашем вопросе мало детализации. Входная точка только router.php? Путь должен преобразоваться в GET параметр?? Будет ли отдельно GET параметр еще передаваться??

```
location / {
   try_files   $uri $uri/ /router.php?$query_string;
}

if (!-d $request_filename) {
   rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Парсить надо на стороне кода. В данном примере весь url в том числе и get параметры будут переданы в router.php